# Parse PFUser Object won't decode

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, parse-server

I am making a query to my parse server and it processes and then it returns user objects. However in my iOS app, when I query, I get back 22 objects which is correct.

The first object has data:
<PFUser[cHs50ntxfu] name:'John Doe' email:'jdoe@example.com' type:0>

The rest don't (eg:):
<PFUser[POGTvJh6Tl] name:'' email:'(null)' type:1>

Here is my basic query:

PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"company" equalTo:[PFCompany currentCompany]];
[query orderByAscending:@"type"];

then:

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
```

(this runs and brings back the objects)

So what is causing these blank records? I checked the database and all the data exists in the User atlas mongodb

Thanks (I edited this because now I know my real problem)

Comment: What is your question about?  Decoding what at what line and how?  Making a query at what line?

Comment: I edited as I now know what the problem is..

Comment: By default the user class is protected and you probably do not have access to retrieve users data directly from the frontend. You probably need to do that using a cloud code function.

Comment: this was a back end query function to the cloud. I don't understand then. Is it some read field level protection? If so where is that set? That makes sense as the first record that comes back is the owner record.

Comment: It is the CLP/ACL setup. The current user will see its own object by default, but not the others. I'd not recommend to make it public as any other user would be able to read all your user table. I'd recommend creating a cloud code function which executes the query on the cloud and return only the data you need to the client.